# how to remove password from pdf documents?

Tags: password, mac, pdf

I recently bought membership to a online course.  It has hundreds of PDFs, and each PDF has a password, a DIFFERENT password at that.  It is too late to get a refund, and I plan to use that knowledge from those PDFs anyway.

Anyway, I don't have the patience to remember 150 passwords - is there any *free* way to remove the passwords from those PDFs?  I am on Mac OS X Lion.  I don't feel like spending more money on this, so am looking for some free tool.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not a MAC person but free PDF printers like PDFCreator can be used to strip off passwords - just open and print into a new PDF.